# Mysql merge multiple records with same id ignoring null fields

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, merging-data

I'm looking to merge a number of records with the same Id into one record per Id. I have had to use pivot tables to get the data I need from multiple other tables and into an interim table that looks something like this:

```
ID |Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4
1   asdf  NULL  NULL  NULL
1   NULL  blah  NULL  NULL
1   NULL  NULL  this  NULL
1   NULL  NULL  NULL  data
2   NULL  funk  NULL  NULL
2   NULL  NULL  jazz  NULL
```

And I would like to find a way to merge all records with the same Id into a new record in a new table that looks like this:

```
ID |Data1|Data2|Data3|Data4
1   asdf  blah  this  data
2   NULL  funk  jazz  NULL
```

I have looked through multiple other similar questions on here and other websites that seem to be dealing with numerical values in the fields such as this one ([Merge multiple rows with same ID into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569589/merge-multiple-rows-with-same-id-into-one-row)). These do not have the desired effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX()` with `GROUP BY` Clause :

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       MAX(t.Data1), 
       MAX(t.Data2), 
       MAX(t.Data3), 
       MAX(t.Data4) 
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Comment: Minor: Why alias if you don't use it ?

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this previously but I was incorrectly using aliases on some of the field titles which was then messing everything else up! All working now :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 value for each column (which seems like it from your data sample) , then you can use aggregation methods:

```
SELECT t.id ,
       max(t.data1) as data1,
       max(t.data2) as data2,
       max(t.data3) as data3,
       max(t.data3) as data3
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id
```